# gedit messes up file names in headline

Tags: gedit

I open several text files in gedit. But when switching to view different text files, the file name shown in the headline of gedit is messed up. So I was wondering if it is a bug and how to solve this problem? Thanks and regards!

For example, when I switched from file1 to file2 by clicking the tab of file2, the main window shows the content of file2, while the headline of gedit shows "file1". If wait 15 seconds or so, the headline will change to "file2".
[image]

P.S. My gedit is gedit 2.30.3 and OS is Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug report here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=642705 similar to yours but mentions that when changing the tabs USING THE SCROLL WHEEL. They mention the problem that the Title takes too long to update.

Anyway just tested using Ubuntu 10.10. Does not happen to me but as the bug suggests and your post here, it happens to some users.